# while loop terminating early with nested if statement

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I'm writing a condition check for a simple input via prompt() in JavaScript.  The idea is to repeat a prompt until the user supplies a positive integer.

In particular, if I submit a negative integer, it correctly prompts me again via case 3.  However, if I answer the second prompt again with a negative integer, the code unexpectedly leaves the while loop.

In the if statement:

Case 1: checks if the user 'cancels' the prompt box (or returns an empty string), in which case I set a variable 'cancelGridCreation' to 'true' to later cancel the encapsulating process (outside of the included code), and then terminate the while loop by setting the variable 'waitingForQualifyingAnswer' to 'false'.

Case 2: checks if the response is an acceptable integer (number, integer, positive), and sets the conditional variable 'false' to terminate the while loop.

Case 3: prompts the user again, with the idea that the newly entered data will be checked again by the same 3 'if' cases.

User inputs matching cases 1 and 2 seem to work fine.  However, as mentioned above, entering a negative integer 2 times terminates the while loop.  See the console output that I received, entering -10 and then -20.  As well, the console.log() outputs don't seem to occur in an order matching their location in the code (perhaps a processing time-lag issue?). You'll see that the console.log() from case 3 outputs before the "initial size entered" console.log(), which is coded before the while loop even starts.

Similar results seem to occur whenever case 3 is followed by another case 3 (regardless whether input is negative integers, decimals, or strings), as well as case 3 followed by case 1 (of course, here case 1 would terminate the loop, but the console log statements still seem to occur out of order).

Link to interactive code at JSBin: https://jsbin.com/koheku/1/edit?js,console

JavaScript Code:

```
let cancelGridCreation = false;
let waitingForQualifyingAnswer = true;
let answer = prompt('Please enter the number of rows/columns, as a positive integer:', '16');
let gridSize = parseFloat(answer, 10);
console.log('initial size entered: ' + gridSize);
while (waitingForQualifyingAnswer === true) {
  console.log('top of while loop');
  if (answer == null || answer == "") {
    console.log('prompt - canceled');     
    cancelGridCreation = true;
    waitingForQualifyingAnswer = false;
  } else if (typeof gridSize === 'number' && gridSize % 1 === 0 && gridSize > 0) {
    console.log('prompt - good answer: ' + gridSize);
    waitingForQualifyingAnswer = false;
  } else {
    console.log('prompt - BAD answer: ' + gridSize);
    answer = prompt('Incorrect format entered.  Please enter the number of rows/columns, as a positive integer:', '16');
    gridSize = parseFloat(answer, 10);
    console.log('new size entered: ' + gridSize);
  }
  console.log('end of while loop');
}
console.log('done:');
console.log(gridSize);
```

Console Output was as follows (having entered -10 at the first prompt, and -20 at the second prompt):

```
    "prompt - BAD answer: -10"
    "top of while loop"
    "initial size entered: -10"
    "new size entered: -20"
    "end of while loop"
    "done:"
    -20
```

I'm pretty new, and realize there may be more concise ways to accomplish this.  I'm interested in suggestions, however, I"m also keen to figure out why the while loop is ending when only case 3 inputs are being submitted.

Please note: The console.log() statements are only of a simple means of debugging.  I realize a parseInt() would truncate any decimals, but I chose to allow integers as an acceptable size.

Thank you for any advice you can offer :)

Comment: Not *quite* sure how you managed to end up with that output, but I'd assume it's due to asynchronous behaviour. I just tested this in both Firefox and Chrome, and got: `initial size entered: -10`, 
`top of while loop`, `prompt - BAD answer: -10`, `new size entered: 16`, `end of while loop`, `top of while loop`, `prompt - good answer: 16`, `end of while loop`, `done:`, `16` in both browsers... which is exactly what I'd expect. What browser were you using when you got that output?

Comment: This would be a good exercise for you to learn how to use the browsers Developer Tools (all browsers have this - press F12 key). Learn how to use breakpoints and single step through your code. Search for the dev tools help by using google.

Comment: Seconding @ObsidianAge over here-- tested in Chrome and output behaved as expected.

Comment: @ObsidianAge no, there's nothing asynchronous about this. It's just buggy code.

Comment: @Pointy - Is `console.log()` not asynchronous?

Comment: @ObsidianAge no, it is not. Well, it sort-of is in Chrome, but that doesn't matter because this code does not depend on the return value of `console.log()`.

Comment: Following......

Comment: Just tried this on chrome for Android. Received the same problem as described in the question.

Comment: Also `parseFloat()` only takes one argument; that `10` is ignored.

Comment: `typeof gridSize === 'number'` is an unnecessary test. It will always be `true`.

Comment: *"I"m also keen to figure out why the while loop is ending when only case 3 inputs are being submitted."* If you're getting that in jsBin, it's because they try to detect possible infinite loops, and will stop your code if found. The developer console gives an indication of this, and shows how to disable this protection.

Comment: I suggest that you learn how to use the developer tools in whatever browser you develop for. For some general tips on debugging, read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/